# How can I link a Container Group with a Container?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

Note: This is a question related to Docker support in Bluemix.

I know how to link a Container with a Container, using --link parameter when starting the second Container with ice run command.

But I haven't found a way to link them, when using a Container Group. I read the docs and check ice command help with no luck.

The scenario I am trying to achieve is to create a front end Container Group linked to a single backend Container. Any idea or suggestion about how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported yet in the current ver of IBM Containers.

You can consider, in the mean time, creating yourself the environment vars, that linking creates.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about that workaround but as everything is deployed automatically from Bluemix DevOps Services, I don't know the private IP that is going to be assigned to MySQL Container.